# User edit is giving ArgumentError in DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While clicking on edit profile link for user I am getting following error

```
ArgumentError in DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#edit
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

My application controller looks like this:

```
def authenticate_user!
 super
 flash[:alert] = nil
end
```

My routes looks like this

```
devise_for :users
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

My Rake routes look likes this

```
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   devise_invitable/registrations#edit
```

The edit url looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/users/edit
```

it should have some id to edit. Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: try this `super(:force => true)`.

Comment: Not working, still getting the same error

Comment: Can you explain what you want? and show `DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController` if you redefine it.

Comment: I just want to Edit the User profile, and while clicking on Edit Profile I am getting argument error.

Comment: You should use another `edit` action, [Devise::InvitationsController#edit](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb#L33) not provide edit user profile function.